# how to assign in ruby without checking each step if the values you assign exist

Tags: ruby

Unfortunately I couldn't think of a really good way to write this question, we have a lot of code that ends up looking like this:

```
@annotation.note = params[:annotation][:note] if params[:annotation][:note]
@annotation.style = params[:annotation][:style] if params[:annotation][:style]
```

I find that if params at the end check annoying.

So is there a way to write this more succinctly, so that it is understood that the value only gets copied over if it exists without having to ask that explicit if at the end each time?

Comment: I think the question can be asked in a more general way. I asked such [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603264) now.

Comment: I think DRY is important, of course, but another important value here is clarity. I'm not very advanced in Ruby so I have to admit of the various solutions presented here the one that makes the most sense to me is Sergios's, because if I was trying to do it in some other language that is what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = params[:annotation][:note] and @annotation.note = x
x = params[:annotation][:style] and @annotation.style = x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily extract the checks into a method, so that your code is more DRY. Like this, for example:

```
def copy obj, prop, params
  val = params[prop]
  obj.send "#{prop}=", val if val
end

ann = params[:annotation]
copy @annotation, :node, ann
copy @annotation, :style, ann
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this:

```
params[:annotation].each_pair {|k,v| v && @annotation.send("#{k}=", v) }
```

some tests:

```
require 'ostruct'

@annotation = OpenStruct.new
params = {:annotation => {:note => 'note', :style => 'style'}}

params[:annotation].each_pair {|k,v| v && @annotation.send("#{k}=", v) }

p @annotation
#<OpenStruct note="note", style="style">

@annotation = OpenStruct.new
params = {:annotation => {:note => nil, :style => 'style'}}

params[:annotation].each_pair {|k,v| v && @annotation.send("#{k}=", v) }

p @annotation
#<OpenStruct style="style">

@annotation = OpenStruct.new
params = {:annotation => {:note => 'note'}}

params[:annotation].each_pair {|k,v| v && @annotation.send("#{k}=", v) }

p @annotation
#<OpenStruct note="note">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params[:annotation][:note].tap{|v| @annotation.note = v if v} 
params[:annotation][:style].tap{|v| @annotation.style = v if v}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method as well:

```
@annotation.note = params[:annotation][:note] || @annotation.note
```

I'll admit, you do repeat `@annotation.note` but the statement length is still reduced.

Comment: How is it reduced? `||` is exactly the same length as `if`. Although, you have a good pararrel with `||=`.

Comment: There's no repeat of params[:annotation][:note].

Answer (score -1):

Here's another attempt:

```
@annotation.note = params[:annotation][:note] rescue nil
```

@annotation.note will remain `nil` if `params[:annotation][:note]` does not exist.