# Syntax sugar for `a = b || a`, `a = b && a`

Tags: ruby

For `a = a || b`, `a = a && b`, there is good syntax sugar `a ||= b`, `a &&= b`. Something that also appears frequently is:

```
a = b || a
a = b && a
```

Is there a good syntax sugar or a short way to write this?

Comment: You really want a shorter way to write this, less than 5 characters?

Comment: @vgoff Do you think I will always be using the exact variable names `a` and `b`? This is just a generalized use case. And furthermore, are you against the syntax sugar `||=` and `&&=`? Why do you think they exist?

Comment: I am interested to find another answer other than 'no'.  This is the syntactic sugar.

Comment: @vgoff, I think the point is to avoid repeating one of variable names.

Comment: @sawa of course I am not against syntactic sugar.  Yet you answer your own question in the question.. "Is there a good syntax sugar or a short way to write this?" Yet, right at the beginning the answer is there "there is good syntax sugar a ||= b" in your own words. Therefore, I must assume you meant syntactic sugar that is sweeter than that.  My answer is "no" you won't find anything with less moving parts than that.  And yes, I know you are reversing the order of to `b || a`

Comment: @vgoff "What it really does" url is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Michiel de Mare.  And no way to change it... So removed.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = b || a
```

can be rewritten as:

```
a = b if b
```

which can be rewritten without repetition of `a` or `b` as

```
x = b and a = x
```

If the expressions `a` and `b` are both longer than 6 characters, `x = b and a = x` is the shortest form.

Comment: The second form is not more readable if b is a 40-character expression.

Comment: any reason to use `and` instead of `&&`

Comment: Operator precedence. `x = b and a = x` is equal to `(x = b) and (a = x)`. However, `x = b && a = x` is equal to `x = (b && (a = x))`

Answer (score 2):

There is no such shortcut currently.

The &&= and ||= are **NODE_OP_ASGN_AND** and **NODE_OP_ASGN_OR** in CRuby/MRI AST. The 'rvalue' is only evaluated if the lvalue is false or nil.

Comment: sawa is asking for the reverse action of `a ||= b` denying the truthy-ness of a rather than relying on the truthyness of b..